# How to Dismiss presentModalViewController controller in iOS5

Tags: iphone

I am new in iphone development. I am working in Xcode4.2, and iOS5 .I have used for navigation one view to another:This working fine..

```
-(IBAction)viewFullProfile:(id)sender
{
    OperatorFullProfile *operatorFullProfile = [[OperatorFullProfile alloc] initWithNibName:@"OperatorFullProfile" bundle:nil];    
    [self presentModalViewController:operatorFullProfile animated:YES];

}
```

But When I dismiss OperatorFullProfile, its did not dismissed. For dismiss code:

```
-(IBAction)Cancel:(id)sender
{
  [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
 // [self.parentViewController.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 // [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil ];
}
```

i am trying for that problem, please help.

Answer (score 1):

Just calling:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```

should do the trick, no need to get the parent viewcontroller.

Comment: Well it should, then the error is some where else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

in your OperatorFullProfile.m file on your cancel button method...

```
-(IBAction)Cancel:(id)sender
{
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];

}
```

and your current this view will dismis...
:)

Comment: then i your method above first method in overwrite this code OperatorFullProfile *operatorFullProfile = [[OperatorFullProfile alloc] initWithNibName:@"OperatorFullProfile" bundle:nil];    
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:operatorFullProfile animated:YES];  use this code for present this view check it....

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` from the `UIViewController` that presents the modal view controller.

A typical (and well designed) way to do this is using a delegate. Let's say the modal controller has a `Done` button. You declare a `@protocol` in your modal view controller, whose method is, let's say, `didTapDoneButton`, and have a `@property` that is an instance of that protocol, let's call it `delegate`.

In the `IBAction`, call

```
-(IBAction)Cancel:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate didTapDoneButton];
}
```

Implement the protocol in the view controller that presents the modal one, and, when you create the modal controller, set its delegate property to `self`.

```
-(IBAction)viewFullProfile:(id)sender
{
    OperatorFullProfile *operatorFullProfile = [[OperatorFullProfile alloc] initWithNibName:@"OperatorFullProfile" bundle:nil];    
    operatorFullProfile.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:operatorFullProfile animated:YES];

}
```

In that class, implement the method of the protocol, that will be called when the button is pressed:

```
-(void)didTapDoneButton
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

That way the controller responsible of presenting the modal controller is also responsible of dismissing it.

Answer (score 0):

Just write:

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];

Cheers.